# php code to display sum of amount column

Tags: php, mysql

I need to filter data based on some condition and display filtered data and also  the total sum values of amount..

but the problem is i have two different query...

below is my code to filter data from database based on fromdate and todate...

The [prob. is my code display data properly but does not display sum of amount column which comes from second condition in fromdate and to date filter....

```
 <?php
    if($_POST && isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {   
        if($_POST['street']!='')
        {
        $street = $_POST['street']; 
        $data = $database->getRows("SELECT *,  GROUP_CONCAT(coupon) as cou,GROUP_CONCAT(coupondate) as coupondt FROM receipt_entry WHERE street =:street GROUP by book_no,receipt_no",array(':street'=>$street)); 
        }   


        elseif($_POST['fromdate']!='' && $_POST['todate']!='')
    {   
    $fromdate = $_POST['fromdate']; 
    $todate = $_POST['todate'];
    $data = $database->getRows("SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(coupon) as cou,GROUP_CONCAT(coupondate) as coupondt FROM receipt_entry WHERE bookingdate BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate GROUP          BY book_no,receipt_no order by bookingdate asc"
    ,array(':fromdate'=>$fromdate,':todate'=>$todate)); 

     $tot = $database->getRows("SELECT SUM(AmountTotal) FROM (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT amount) AS AmountTotal, receipt_no  FROM receipt_entry where bookingdate BETWEEN :fromdate AND     :todate GROUP BY receipt_no) AS T1",array(':fromdate'=>$fromdate,':todate'=>$todate)); 
    } 


        }
    ?>


<table>
        <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th width="4%">Sr.No</th>
            <th width="12%">Book / Recpt</th>            

        </tr>
        </thead>

         <tbody>
           <?php foreach($data as $row){ ?>         
            <tr>
             <td></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['book_no']); ?> / <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['receipt_no']); ?></td>     

        </tr>   
        </tbody>
        <?php  }?>

<?php foreach($tot as $tota) {?>
    <tr><td colspan="8"><?php echo $tota['AmountTotal']; ?></td></tr>           
    <?php }  ?> 
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually query two times using both mentioned query then merge it in single associative array in $data variable.

```
 $d = $database->getRows("SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(coupon) as cou,GROUP_CONCAT(coupondate) as coupondt FROM receipt_entry WHERE bookingdate BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate GROUP          BY book_no,receipt_no order by bookingdate asc"
,array(':fromdate'=>$fromdate,':todate'=>$todate)); 
 $tot = $database->getRows("SELECT SUM(AmountTotal) FROM (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT amount) AS AmountTotal, receipt_no  FROM receipt_entry where bookingdate BETWEEN :fromdate AND     :todate GROUP BY receipt_no) AS T1",array(':fromdate'=>$fromdate,':todate'=>$todate));
 $data = array('data'=>$d, 'total'=>$tot);
```

Then you can pass $data anywhere to use both values.

Comment: i put my complete code ...in my post...the prob..is data display properly but my  $$tot query not get sum of amouint column and not display amount below table......but when i run this query in database this works perfectly...

Comment: try using echo $tot['SUM(AmountTotal)'];

Comment: and what does echo $tot; prints out